# How to fetch data from DB according to array element without using loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have multiple id's in an array, and I want to print cat_name..
Here is my code in CI...

```
$business_cat   = $this->input->post('cat_id');

$business_sub_cat= $this->input->post('sub_cat_id');

$msg="<td><b>Business Catagories :</b></td><td>".implode(", ", $business_cat)."</td>
                        </tr><tr>   
                            <td><b>Business Subcatagories :</b></td><td>".implode(", ", $business_sub_cat)."</td>";
```

But I want to print cat_name instead of id's, but when I use foreach loop b/w

it print error.
can Anyone help me out.
Thanxx in advance

Comment: where is `cat_name` in your code. also plz show `post values`.

Comment: where is the foreach loop you are talking about.

Comment: add more specific code

Comment: cat_name is in database and i want to fetch and print cat_name from table

Comment: @Plum I tried but it throw error thats why I removed it from code

Comment: @SonuBamniya you only added partial code here.... you didn't interact with database also. Add complete code plz.

Comment: @Yash i have used everything and everything is working properly I just want to print data of table using its primary key id but without using loop is this possible or not

Comment: its possible and you don't need to use any `loop`. if you are getting 1 row than simply use `row_array()` during `database fetching` on the basis of `primary key(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...    // mark this is a demo code only

```
$business_cat   = $this->input->post('cat_id');
$cat_name = array();
foreach($business_cat  as $key=>$cat_id )
{
    $cat_name[] = "demo cat name ". $key;//take name from database using $cat_id.... 
}
$cat_name_str = implode(", ", $cat_name);
$business_sub_cat = $this->input->post('sub_cat_id');
$sub_cat = array();
foreach($business_sub_cat  as $key=>$sub_cat_id )
{
    $sub_cat[] = "demo sub cat name ". $key;//take name from database using $sub_cat_id.... 
}
$sub_name_str = implode(", ", $sub_cat);

$msg = "<td><b>Business Catagories :</b></td><td>$cat_name_str</td></tr><tr><td><b>Business Subcatagories :</b></td><td>$sub_name_str</td>";
```